# Adding custom price calculation to price in Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I hope one can help me.
So in order to calculate price i need 2 inputs from the customer, based on the small script i made down below i need the output (total price) to add up to the shopify liquid price

```
<script> 
function calc() {   
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount2").value;  
    var amount = parseInt(amount, 10);  
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity2").value;  
    var quantity = parseInt(quantity, 10);  
    var total = amount * quantity / 10000 * 72 / 100 * 40 + 90; 
    document.getElementById("custom-total2").value = total;
} 
</script>

<label for="Breedte">Breedte:
    <input type="" id="amount2" name="properties[Breedte]" placeholder="voer uw breedte in CM" name="amount2" oninput="calc();">
</label>
<label for="Hoogte">Hoogte:
    <input type="" id="quantity2" name="properties[Hoogte]" placeholder="voer uw hoogte in CM" name="quantity2" oninput="calc();">
</label>
<label for="Prijs">Prijs
    <input type="" id="custom-total2" name="custom-total2"> 
</label>
```

Is their anyway i can get "custom-total2" add up to the price? i suppose i need to do this in every liquid file price is shown?

the formula works so far

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to check that the computed price and the product's price are the same ? Do you have access to the liquid price variable ? Generally, you can use liquid in your JS code. This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587159/accessing-shopify-liquid-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, the thing is i can't find the liquid code which is responsible for product price and going through to cart and check out of course. The link you send says its not possible accessing or linking through liquid files with JS? So that means that you need to code everything in JS in order to get relevant variables through to the check out?

Comment: You can't pass JS variables to liquid code but you can access liquid variables inside JS code. I meant that if you have access to the liquid price variable of the product then you can fetch it inside your JS code to check that the computed price and the original price match. Aren't you appending your script after a liquid 'product' template ? If so, you have access to the `product.price` variable.